# Adding Python Text Area To Existing Program

Tags: python, text, textbox, tkinter

I have a little python program. I'm using Tkinter for a GUI. I have a bunch of grid style text boxes, but i want to add a small text area. All the examples Ive tried work, but open in a new window.

I want the last grid labeled "description" to be a small text area instead, As it would be used for a few sentences rather than a few words. Also im going to need to "get()" this input to use as a variable.

Here is my script.( I left out a few parts that might bring up errors )
from Tkinter import *

```
master = Tk()
Label(master, text="Stock #").grid(row=0, sticky=W)
Label(master, text="Type").grid(sticky=W,  row=1)
Label(master, text="Make").grid(sticky=W,  row=2)
Label(master, text="Model").grid(sticky=W,  row=3)
Label(master, text="GVW").grid(sticky=W,  row=0, column=2)
Label(master, text="Description").grid(sticky=W,  row=1, column=2)

e1 = Entry(master)
e2 = Entry(master)
e3 = Entry(master)
e4 = Entry(master)
e24 = Entry(master)
e25 = Entry(master)


e1.grid(row=0, column=1, pady=5, padx=(0,30))
e2.grid(row=1, column=1, pady=5, padx=(0,30))
e3.grid(row=2, column=1, pady=5, padx=(0,30))
e4.grid(row=3, column=1, pady=5, padx=(0,30))
e24.grid(row=0, column=3, pady=5, padx=(0,10))
e24.insert(0, "N/A")
e25.grid(row=1, column=3, pady=5, padx=(0,10))
e25.insert(0, "N/A")


mainloop( )
```

Comment: Please don't post your entire program, post a stripped-down version that demonstrates your problem/request with as little code as possible. See [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more info.

Comment: Also, creating variables named `e1` through `e25` is almost never a good idea. Why not just create a single list named `entries` with 25 elements in it? Among other benefits, that would mean that, instead of 75 lines of code, you can use a 5-line `for` loop to create all of them. And if you wanted to, e.g., change the padding later, you'd just have to change 1 line instead of 25. (Especially since you're virtually guaranteed to miss one of those 25 and spend all day chasing down a stupid bug, unless you have a much better eye than me or anyone else I've worked with…)

Comment: Well, I _did_ have time enough to help, which is why I wrote a whole answer, but if you're going to be snotty about it, maybe I should delete it. You're the one who's begging other people to volunteer their time to helping you; if asking you to follow the rules of the site, which are there for a good reason, is insulting, you can go find another community to help you.

Comment: "snotty", "begging". I didn't catch that. I'm simply asking for help. If my thread is not up to your standards than just ignore it.

Comment: "Just for you", "Since you have enough time to correct my mistakes, maybe you can give me some help". You really weren't being snide and snotty? In that case, you may want to read your comments out loud and try to imagine how they would sound to other people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want the last grid labeled "description" to be a small text area instead, As it would be used for a few sentences rather than a few words.

As the [`Entry`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm) docs tell you:

> To enter multiple lines of text, use the `Text` widget.

So:

```
text = Text(master)
text.grid(row=whatever, etc.)
```

> Also im going to need to "get()" this input to use as a variable.

I'm not sure what you mean here. If you mean you wanted to attach a `StringVar`, you can't do that with `Text`, sadly, only with `Entry`. But if you want to be able to fetch the contents in some way, you don't care which way, then that's easy; the [`Text`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm) docs will show you how a variety of different ways, but I think `text.get(1.0, END)` is the one you'll probably want.

Comment: This is a great response. I can appreciate this.

Comment: Seems like this is what i was looking for. Will keep your comments in mind on my next post.